# Difference between elements and subsets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

What is the difference between elements in a set and subsets? Why isn’t a subset also an element of a set? Or is it? I’ve been told that the two are totally different relations, but I struggle to understand the difference. Is it a matter of their logical consequences, the rules by which they’re governed, something else? I suppose what I’m asking is: Since subsets belong, like elements, to other sets, why wouldn’t they be elements too?

Comment: Related [Quora link](https://www.quora.com/Discrete-Mathematics-What-is-the-difference-between-being-an-element-of-a-set-or-being-a-subset-of-a-set)

Answer (score 3):

The elements of a set $S$ are the things inside the set. A subset is a set you form using only elements inside the set $S$.

Sets with single elements are called singletons, like $P = \{1\}$.

No, a subset is not an element of the set, as elements are fundamentally *things* that are not sets and subsets are fundamentally *sets*. As $\text{set} \neq \text{things that are not sets}$, they are not the same.

Take $S = \{1, 2, 3\}$. The elements are 1, 2 and 3, but the subsets are {1}, {1,2}, {1, 3}, and so on.

Also, a set containing a single element is not the element itself.

Here’s another view: In set builder notation, imagine any set $A = \{a, b, c, d, e, \cdots\}$. Here, the things separated by commas are elements. If you chose any combination of these elements, and make the set of those elements, you got a subset.

A *proper* subset is a subset where you strictly don’t choose the original full set. All subsets except that one are proper subsets.

Take this:

Here we have 5 points in a plane (blue):

[image]

Now, circle any combination of these. Imagine I circle like this (green):

[image]

Green is a subset. However, none of these will be the actual points. Hence we have subsets and not elements.

And when you circle it in any other combination, you would get another subset.

If you’re up for some rigor, we could define them like this

In $A = \{a_1, a_2, \cdots a_n\}$, $a_i$ is an element.

$A \subset B \iff \forall x \in A, \exists x \in B$, which in simple English basically translates to

“$A$ is a subset of $B$ if and only if for every element $x$ inside $A$, there exists $x$ inside of $B$.”

Here, $\iff$ denotes “if and only if”.

---

I hope this makes the distinction (really) clear!

Comment: Oh, okay. So is it the case that, technically, subsets aren’t “inside” of sets, or maybe that it’s misleading to think of them that way? In other words, if I’ve got a set of five marbles inside of an ring, and I place three marbles to the side, have I created a subset?

Comment: @inkd If those three marbles were taken from the original five, you made a subset.

Comment: @inkd thinking of subsets as “Inside sets” is completely fine, but the more involved definition is that it is a set you form using only elements from the original set. We define a proper subset as a subset where you use less elements. For example, if you have a set $P$ of five points in a plane, the set of four points in a plane is a subset, and it is technically “inside” the set (if you wish to think of it that way).

Comment: @inkd I added another view that might be more intuitive

Comment: The illustration is definitely helpful. And so it sounds like subsets are more about formation than being “inside” of something. If you were to move three points from the original circle to another, you would have created, or “formed”, a subset?

Comment: @inkd Yes! If that circle represents a set. Also: if $A$ is a subset of $B$, and $B$ is a subset of $C$, then $A$ is a subset of $C$. If you move 4 of 5 points in a set to another set, that “another set” is a subset

Comment: Would you mind saying more about the formula? What is a-sub-i? (why not a-sub-n?) And is the dual arrow a symbol for ‘if and only if’? How would you translate this into English?

Comment: @ink I have shared the info about the formula in the question. About the $a_i$, first realize we have a set $P = \{a_1, a_2, \cdots a_n\}$ where there are $n$ elements. To denote any of these $a$, we use $a_i$, where you can think of $i$ as an “index”.

Comment: @inkd we can’t use $a_n$ as thats already defined; it’s the last element

Comment: Is it also the case that to call a subset an element is to (mistakenly) imply that it’s somehow something over and above the elements that comprise it? Would calling a subset an element be a mistake akin to supposing a subset comprising elephants to itself be an elephant?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps some examples will make the distinction clearer.

- {1,2} is a set with two elements: 1 and 2.
- {1} is a set with one element: 1.
- 1 is not a set.
- {{1},2} is a set with two elements: {1} and 2. Here, {1} is an element of {{1},2} and it is also a set.
- {} is a set with no elements.
- {{}} is a set with one element: {}. Here, {} is an element of {{}} and it is also a set.
- {{1,2}} is a set with one element: {1,2}. Here, 1 is an element of {1,2} but it is not an element of {{1,2}}.

Comment: Consider $\{ \{1\}, 2\}$. Here $\{1\}$ is an element but $\{\{1\}\}$ is a subset.

Answer (score 0):

If a set is a bowl of cereal, then each of the pieces of cereal is an element, and the subsets are all the possible bowls of cereal you could get by taking out some (or possibly none, or possibly all) of the cereal.

"But", I hear you say, "couldn't I take out all except for a single piece?". And the answer is yes, you can, but we distinguish between a single piece of cereal and a bowl containing just a single piece of cereal. The former is $a\in A$, an element, and the latter is $\{a\}\subset A$, a subset.

Note: It is possible for a bowl of cereal to contain a mix of pieces of cereal and other bowls of cereal. And in that case the contained bowl is an element of the containing bowl. It can get complicated. So you should probably start with getting a good understanding of the situation in the first paragraph, and then move on to thinking about bowls-inside-bowls.